# Erlang Receive and proper call structure

Tags: memory, erlang, heap-memory

Can the following be done in erlang and not generate a crash due to memory heap issues?

```
loop() ->
   receive
      {drop, X}  -> drop(X);
      X -> handle(X)
   end.

handle(X) ->
   case X of
     ok -> loop()
   end.

drop(X) -> 
  case X of
     ok -> loop()
   end.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy enough to try and see what happens:

```
-module(loop).
-compile(export_all).
loop() ->
   receive
      {drop, X}  -> drop(X);
   after 1000 ->
      erlang:display(catch erlang:error(noes)),
      drop(ok)
   end.

drop(X) ->
  case X of
     ok -> loop()
   end.
```

If you run loop:loop() you'll see that it does infact not grow the stack. If you add a ,1 after the call to drop(ok) or loop() you will see the stack growing.

So the compiler figures out that it is a tail call and optimises it even though it is not a recursive tail-call.

Comment: Yes, the compiler handles **all** tail-calls in this way.

Answer (score 1):

My gut guess is no, as the functions as written are not tail recursive.